# bootstrap collapse not working after append()

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-4

On ajax success call I append the content to the element with id `#special-contents` but when the page load the collapse button is not expanding the panel. Here's my javascript code

```
$.ajax({
        url: `${URL}/promotions/`,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            
            var promotions = response.promotions;

            var specialPromotions       = filterByCategory(promotions, 'special');

            for (var i = 0; i < specialPromotions.length; i++) {
                var specialPromotion = specialPromotions[i];

                // Append
                $('#special-contents').append(
                    `<div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel">
                            <div class="promotionBox promotionBox1">
                                <div class="promotionImage">
                                    <img src="${specialPromotion.banner}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="promotionDesc promotionDesc1">
                                    <p>${specialPromotion.title}</p>
                                    <button data-category="Special" class="promotion-details btnShadow" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="special-${specialPromotion.id}" aria-expanded="false">
                                        View Details
                                    </button>
                                    <a href="${specialPromotion.btn_link}" class="btnShadow"
                                                        target="_blank">Visit</a>
                                    <div id="special-${specialPromotion.id}" class="panel-collapse collapse ">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                            <div class="promotionDetailsContent">
                                                ${specialPromotion.content}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`
                );
            }
            
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching promotions:', error);
        }
    });
```

when added it directly to the `#special-contents` element (static content) the collapse is working.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this way will solve the issue, storing the element in a variable and reload the bootstrap collapse.

```
for (var i = 0; i < specialPromotions.length; i++) {
                    var specialPromotion = specialPromotions[i];

                    var visitBtn = specialPromotion.btn_link ? `<a href="${specialPromotion.btn_link}" class="btnShadow" target="_blank">Visit</a>` : '';
                    
                    // Append
                    var newElement = $(
                        `<div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="panel">
                                <div class="promotionBox promotionBox1">
                                    <div class="promotionImage">
                                        <img src="${specialPromotion.banner}">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="promotionDesc promotionDesc1">
                                        <p>${specialPromotion.title}</p>
                                        <button data-category="Special" class="promotion-details btnShadow" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#special-${specialPromotion.id}" aria-expanded="false">
                                            View Details
                                        </button>
                                        ${visitBtn}
                                        <div id="special-${specialPromotion.id}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                <div class="promotionDetailsContent">
                                                    ${specialPromotion.content}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>`
                    );

                    $('#special-contents').append(newElement);
                }

                newElement.find('[data-toggle="collapse"]').collapse();
```